# Getting Java IO Exception while logging the Webmethods Designer 9.12

Tags: designer, webmethods

I am getting the Java IO Exception while connecting the Webmethods Designer 9.12.

Connection failed for localhost:5555 (java.io.IOException)
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

I can able to access the IS admin page and tried looking error in the server log 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDfeK.jpg)

but didnot get anything in particular. Below is the error screenshot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1dJK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What are your settings? Should be without SSL, can you check?

[image: IS connection details in Designer]

Are you able to open http://localhost:5555 in browser?